# Church and City tax details not clear from wiki

Tags: crusader-kings-2

...to me at least. Reading the following three articles - http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Tax [1],

http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Demesne_income [2], and http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Liege_tax [3] -, I have the following questions/conclusions/guesses and would love if someone experienced could lay this out clearly:

(a) Cities and Temples in counties in my own demesne only contribute to my demesne income per [2], not additionally also per church/temple tax?

(b) Cities and Temples in counties/duchies/etc of my *vassals* are taxed based on the city/church tax I set? I conclude (guess) this because, despite of 0% feudal tax rate, I see significant church and city income (which, if (a) is true, must be from vassal regions)

(c) Once I set the feudal tax rate to higher than 0%, and assuming (b) is true, will this lead to double taxation of temples/cities in regions owned by my vassals?

I'm all new, and find the wiki description not that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much much simpler than you're making it out to be.

- You get 100% of the listed income from holdings you personally hold (aka your demesne), barring penalties for recently conquered, holding the wrong type (e.g. city when you're feudal), etc.
- The tax rates you set are for your direct vassals only. This is applied to whatever their final income ends up being - their demesne income + whatever they tax their vassals at. Note that they set their own tax rate for their vassals (aka your sub-vassals)!

Comment: Thank! Together with certain mouse-over tooltip modifiers I just discovered (in vassal tab; and in the income summary), it makes sense now. Could you remind me what the difference between "base tax" and "tax" is? Is "tax" = base tax after modifiers?

Comment: @gnometorule I think the only place base tax shows up is in the construction window (iirc), and yes, that's the base income before modifiers.